# Laravel query two table

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

Hello just a question from a newbie i just to query this two and i want the second table to be inside the array of the other table.

the table looks like this

bulletin

```
|d : 1"|
|content: "test"|
|id : 2|
|content: "test2"|
```

images

```
|id : 1|
|bulletin_id: 1|
|upload_name: 1.jpg|
|id : 2|
|bulletin_id: 1|
|upload_name: 2.jpg|
|id : 3|
|bulletin_id: 2|
|upload_name: 3.jpg|
|id : 4|
|bulletin_id: 2|
|upload_name: 2.jpg|
```

my query looks like this

```
$bulletin = DB::table('bulletin')
            ->select('bulletin.id','content','upload_name')
            ->join('images', 'images.bulletin_id', '=', 'bulletin.id')
            ->get();
```

is it possible to get this data look like this

```
array
(
  id:1,
  content:test,
  upload_name:array
(
   1.jpg,
   2.jpg
)
)
```

Comment: You can using the Eloquent ORM and defining [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define your models.

```php
php artisan make:model Bulletin
php artisan make:model Image
```

**App\Bulletin.php**

```php
protected $table = 'bulletin';
```

Then the relationship:

**App\Bulletin.php**

```php
use Image;

//

public function upload_name()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

So now you can query your objects:

**app\Http\Controllers\BulletinController.php**

```php
public function index()
{
    $bulletins = Bulletin::with('upload_name')->get();

    return $bulletins;
}
```